# left/camera_info, left/image_raw and right of them not published

Tags: camera, stere-image-proc, camera-driver

I use an OAK-D Pro W camera for ORB-SLAM3 on Ubuntu 20.04 inside WSL 2 (Windows 11).

I run the following command

```
roslaunch depthai_examples stereo_inertial_node.launch
```

Below is my launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <!-- <args for urdf/> -->
    <arg name="mxId"                 default=""/>
    <arg name="usb2Mode"             default="false"/>
    <arg name="poeMode"              default="false"/>

    <arg name="camera_model"         default="OAK-D"            /> <!-- 'zed' or 'zedm' -->
    <arg name="tf_prefix"            default="oak"              />
    <arg name="mode"                 default="depth"            />
    <arg name="base_frame"           default="oak-d_frame"      />
    <arg name="parent_frame"         default="oak-d-base-frame" /> 
    <arg name="imuMode"              default="1"                />   <!-- 0 -> COPY, 1 -> LINEAR_INTERPOLATE_GYRO, 2 -> LINEAR_INTERPOLATE_ACCEL -->

    <arg name="cam_pos_x"             default="0.0" /> <!-- Position respect to base frame (i.e. "base_link) -->
    <arg name="cam_pos_y"             default="0.0" /> <!-- Position respect to base frame (i.e. "base_link) -->
    <arg name="cam_pos_z"             default="0.0" /> <!-- Position respect to base frame (i.e. "base_link) -->
    <arg name="cam_roll"              default="0.0" /> <!-- Orientation respect to base frame (i.e. "base_link) -->
    <arg name="cam_pitch"             default="0.0" /> <!-- Orientation respect to base frame (i.e. "base_link) -->
    <arg name="cam_yaw"               default="0.0" /> <!-- Orientation respect to base frame (i.e. "base_link) -->

    <arg name="lrcheck"               default="true" /> 
    <arg name="extended"              default="false"/> 
    <arg name="subpixel"              default="true" />
    <arg name="rectify"               default="true" />
    <arg name="depth_aligned"         default="true" />
    <arg name="manualExposure"        default="false"/>
    <arg name="expTime"               default="20000"/>
    <arg name="sensIso"               default="800" />

    <arg name="enableSpatialDetection" default="true" />
    <arg name="syncNN"                 default="true" />
    <arg name="detectionClassesCount"  default="80"   />
    <arg name="nnName"                 default="x"         />
    <arg name="resourceBaseFolder"     default="$(find depthai_examples)/resources" />

    <!-- <arg name="nnPath"                 default="" /> -->

     <!-- see https://docs.luxonis.com/projects/api/en/latest/components/nodes/stereo_depth/#currently-configurable-blocks for possible combination of optionf for higher fps-->
    <arg name="stereo_fps"            default="15"  />
    <arg name="confidence"            default="200" />
    <arg name="LRchecktresh"          default="5"   />
    <arg name="monoResolution"        default="720p"/>

    <arg name="rgbResolution"           default="1080p"/>
    <arg name="rgbScaleNumerator"       default="2"/>
    <arg name="rgbScaleDinominator"     default="3"/>
    <arg name="previewWidth"            default="416"/>
    <arg name="previewHeight"           default="416"/>

    <arg name="angularVelCovariance"  default="0"   />
    <arg name="linearAccelCovariance" default="0"   />

    <arg name="enableDotProjector"    default="false"/>
    <arg name="enableFloodLight"      default="false"/>
    <arg name="dotProjectormA"        default="200.0"/>
    <arg name="floodLightmA"          default="200.0"/>
    <arg name="enableRviz"            default="true"/>
    <arg name="enableMarkerPublish"   default="false" />

    <arg name="enableRosBaseTimeUpdate" default="false" />  <!-- Used to handle when ROS time shifts and steady_clock does not -->

    <include file="$(find depthai_descriptions)/launch/urdf.launch">
        <arg name="base_frame"      value="$(arg  base_frame)"  />
        <arg name="parent_frame"    value="$(arg  parent_frame)"/>
        <arg name="camera_model"    value="$(arg  camera_model)"/>
        <arg name="tf_prefix"       value="$(arg  tf_prefix)" />
        <arg name="cam_pos_x"       value="$(arg  cam_pos_x)"   />
        <arg name="cam_pos_y"       value="$(arg  cam_pos_y)"   />
        <arg name="cam_pos_z"       value="$(arg  cam_pos_z)"   />
        <arg name="cam_roll"        value="$(arg  cam_roll)"    />
        <arg name="cam_pitch"       value="$(arg  cam_pitch)"   />
        <arg name="cam_yaw"         value="$(arg  cam_yaw)"     />
    </include>

    <!-- launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb (add [- - args] without space) -->
    <node name="stereo_inertial_publisher" pkg="depthai_examples" type="stereo_inertial_node" output="screen" required="true">
        <param name="mxId"                  value="$(arg mxId)"/>
        <param name="usb2Mode"              value="$(arg usb2Mode)"/>
        <param name="poeMode"               value="$(arg poeMode)"/>

        <param name="tf_prefix"             value="$(arg tf_prefix)"/>
        <param name="mode"                  value="$(arg mode)"/>
        <param name="imuMode"               value="$(arg imuMode)"/>

        <param name="lrcheck"               value="$(arg lrcheck)"/>
        <param name="extended"              value="$(arg extended)"/>
        <param name="subpixel"              value="$(arg subpixel)"/>
        <param name="rectify"               value="$(arg rectify)" />
        <param name="depth_aligned"         value="$(arg depth_aligned)" />
        <param name="manualExposure"        value="$(arg manualExposure)" />
        <param name="expTime"               value="$(arg expTime)" />
        <param name="sensIso"               value="$(arg sensIso)" />
        
        <param name="enableSpatialDetection"   value="$(arg enableSpatialDetection)" />
        <param name="syncNN"                   value="$(arg syncNN)" />
        <param name="detectionClassesCount"    value="$(arg detectionClassesCount)" />
        <param name="nnName"                   value="$(arg nnName)"/>
        <param name="resourceBaseFolder"       value="$(arg resourceBaseFolder)"/>

        <param name="stereo_fps"            value="$(arg stereo_fps)" />
        <param name="confidence"            value="$(arg confidence)" />
        <param name="LRchecktresh"          value="$(arg LRchecktresh)" />
        <param name="monoResolution"        value="$(arg monoResolution)" />

        <param name="rgbResolution"         value="$(arg rgbResolution)" />
        <param name="rgbScaleNumerator"     value="$(arg rgbScaleNumerator)" />
        <param name="rgbScaleDinominator"   value="$(arg rgbScaleDinominator)" />
        <param name="previewWidth"          value="$(arg previewWidth)" />
        <param name="previewHeight"         value="$(arg previewHeight)" />

        <param name="angularVelCovariance"  value="$(arg angularVelCovariance)" />
        <param name="linearAccelCovariance" value="$(arg linearAccelCovariance)" />

        <param name="enableDotProjector"    value="$(arg enableDotProjector)" />
        <param name="enableFloodLight"      value="$(arg enableFloodLight)" />
        <param name="dotProjectormA"        value="$(arg dotProjectormA)" />
        <param name="floodLightmA"          value="$(arg floodLightmA)" />
        <param name="enableRosBaseTimeUpdate" value="$(arg enableRosBaseTimeUpdate)" />
    </node>            

    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager"  args="manager" output="screen"/>

    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="depth_image_convertion_nodelet"
        args="load depth_image_proc/convert_metric nodelet_manager">
        <remap from="image_raw" to="/stereo_inertial_publisher/stereo/depth"/>    
        <remap from="image" to="/stereo_inertial_publisher/stereo/image"/>
    </node>


    <node if="$(eval arg('depth_aligned') == true)" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="depth_image_to_rgb_pointcloud"
        args="load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb nodelet_manager">
        <param name="queue_size"          value="10"/>

        <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="stereo_inertial_publisher/color/camera_info"/>
        <remap from="rgb/image_rect_color" to="stereo_inertial_publisher/color/image"/>
        <remap from="depth_registered/image_rect" to="stereo_inertial_publisher/stereo/image"/>    
        <remap from="depth_registered/points" to="stereo_inertial_publisher/stereo/points"/>
    </node>

    <node if="$(eval arg('depth_aligned') == false)" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="depth_image_to_pointcloud"
        args="load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz nodelet_manager">
        <param name="queue_size"          value="10"/>
        <remap from="camera_info" to="stereo_inertial_publisher/stereo/camera_info"/>
        <remap from="image_rect" to="stereo_inertial_publisher/stereo/image"/>    
        <remap from="points" to="stereo_inertial_publisher/stereo/points"/>
    </node>


    <node if="$(eval arg('enableMarkerPublish') == true)" type="markerPublisher.py" name="markerPublisher" pkg="depthai_examples">
        <remap from="spatialDetections" to="stereo_inertial_publisher/color/yolov4_Spatial_detections"/>
        <remap from="spatialDetectionMarkers" to="stereo_inertial_publisher/color/spatialDetectionMarkers"/>
    </node>

  <group if="$(eval arg('enableRviz') == true)">
    <node if="$(eval arg('depth_aligned') == true)" type="rviz" name="rviz" pkg="rviz" args="-d $(find depthai_examples)/rviz/stereoInertialDepthAlign.rviz" />
    <node if="$(eval arg('depth_aligned') == false)" type="rviz" name="rviz" pkg="rviz" args="-d $(find depthai_examples)/rviz/stereoInertialROS1.rviz" />
  </group>

</launch>
```

and run

```
ROS_NAMESPACE=/stereo_inertial_publisher/ 
rosrun stereo_image_proc stereo_image_proc
```

but `left/image_raw`, `left/camera_info` and `right` of them do not appear in `rostopic`. How can I get them?